# implementing encryption in C application with asynchronous sockets

Tags: c, ssl, encryption

I have a standalone application (client) and the server which is talking my own protocol. Now, I have to implement encryption so third parties can't see any customer's data. I thought about using OpenSSL, but OpenSSL is not designed to work with asynchronous sockets in Edge Triggered mode (server side is written in C and uses epoll, linux only).

What alternatives to OpenSSL do you recommend under LGPL or BSD license so that it would provide same level of security as SSL, but is easier to integrate and works well with asynchronous sockets?

Comment: SSL can work with asynchronous sockets. Google for "non-blocking openssl examples" to see how it is done with the OpenSSL library.

Comment: yes it works with asynchronous sockets, but not with Edge Triggered events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL/TLS has nothing to do with the way sockets are handled, I assume you were talking about OpenSSL. 
OpenSSL can be used with sockets in edge-triggered mode, see for example how libevent (bufferevent_openssl.c) or libcurl are using it.

You have several options though, as PolarSSL, CyaSSL and GnuTLS all support asynchronous usage.

Comment: sorry, question edited, you are right i was talking about OpenSSL